# How to Open .WMV file in Windows media play in Windows 8 by C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am opening videos in Windows Media play by C# Application, After installing application its working on Windows 7 but its not working on Windows 8

Here is my code

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\Avinash\InnovEdge\Videos\Electromagnetic.wmv");

    }
```

Comment: Process.Start will open on your "Default" application, are you sure you've selected a default media player for .wmv types?

Comment: I am opening .WMV Files from DVD...